# boost::function static member variable

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to store a boost::function as a static variable where the "reference?" is fetched from a function.

The variable looks like this:

```
static boost::function<void( const wchar_t*, const bool)> s_logMessage;
```

When I try to compile I get the error:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class boost::function Gorbatras_Converter::ConverterApp::s_logMessage" (?s_logMessage@ConverterApp@Gorbatras_Converter@@2V?$function@$$A6AXPB_W_N@Z@boost@@A)

I've noticed that if I don't use the variable I can compile it without that error (guess it's a compiler optimization since it's not used) but as soon as I try to use the s_logMessage variable I get the linker error.

My way of setting s_logMessage looks like this:

```
const int ConverterApp::RunConverter( boost::function<void( const wchar_t* a_message, const bool a_newLine)> a_logMessage )
{
    ConverterApp::s_logMessage = a_logMessage;    
    ...
}
```

I've tried setting it as a non-static member variable and then it appears to work. But I need it as static, otherwise I might just aswell send it along as a parameter which I don't want as it's going to be a lot of functions.

If you wonder why I'm sending a log function as parameter, that is because it comes from a separate program.

So what I need help is how do I save the boost::function function in a static variable?

Comment: Small hint: note that you can *compile* it without error in both cases. It's the *linker* that issues the error (when appropriate).

Comment: You need a definition at namespace scope: `boost::function<void( const wchar_t*, const bool)> ConverterApp::s_logMessage;`

Comment: I disagree about the dupe. The linked question asks for much more than what is needed to know to solve the issue in this question. Someone who first has to read through pages of text is not satisfied by stackoverflow and will try to look into the next-up google results. Voting to reopen...

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: What happened to _reading_ and _research_?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit reading won't help if you don't need the information you read. research is good, but not if you aren't up to it and just want to get quick help (I am all for voting for dupe, and avoiding to spread good answers over multiple questions. but doing over-agressive close votes just (or largely?) to force people to do "reading and research" seems wrong. Stackoverflow is not that).

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Hardly "over-aggressive". We have FAQs for a purpose. Flooding SO with open duplicates all over the place is not helpful in the grand scheme. The OP may get their answer and be happy, but they have learned the lazy way. There is _nothing_ wrong with encouraging some effort and research.

Comment: I have to agree with @JohannesSchaub-litb on this one. Taking a question that can be answered (as Andy Prowl has) in a total of 5 lines of text, all directly relevant to the question at hand, and instead redirecting to a question with an answer that's closer to 5 *pages* long, especially where the OP nearly needs to already know the correct answer to realize how any of it relates to his question, isn't really doing anybody any good. By this measure, well over 90% of the C++ questions on SO could be closed with a redirection to the Book list.

Answer (score 5):

You're missing a *definition* for the static data member (you only have a *declaration* of that member in your class definition). Put the following at namespace scope:

```
boost::function<void( const wchar_t*, const bool)> ConverterApp::s_logMessage;
```

If you never use the data member (technically, if it is not *odr-used*, see paragraph 3.2 of the C++11 Standard), then the definition is not needed - hence the behavior you are observing.

Comment: Are we going to write this answer identically on every single static data member question, or use the _close as duplicate_ function?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It takes me less to write it than to look for a duplicate, and it takes less time for the OP to understand this answer than to figure out how their question is related to the linked one. Are we to look for duplicates every time the OP is missing a semicolon?

Comment: When the OP is missing a semicolon, we shall close as _too localised_. SO is not a crowdsourced code debugging machine. And the OP should get used to spending more than twenty seconds on his problem - if having to actually _read_ an existing Stack Overflow answer is one step of that training then so be it! You are encouraging help vampirism.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Fine, deleting and voting to close.